# How should I announce that I'm leaving?

Tags: announcements, quitting

I've been offered a 3-year Lecturer III appointment at a top 10 university in my field.  It's an opportunity that fell in my lap, not something I sought, but it's obviously not something I can just pluck from a tree anytime I like.  So of course I'm going to take it.  I'm trying to decide how to announce that I'm leaving and what to say about it.

I've been a lecturer at a state university for four years, PT since my FT contract ran out last year and not currently scheduled for any new assignments.  My colleagues like me and I'm leaving on very good terms.  Both my current chairman and my previous chair (who recruited me) insist I should take this.

How would you announce your departure? Or would you leave that up to your chairman?  What do you say to students?

Comment: Given that you're writing under your real name, I think you just announced your departure to everyone.

Comment: True, but anyone who should find out personally already knows.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton Well, in that case - what's the worry? Congratulations, by the way!

Comment: Related https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38179/how-to-keep-plans-for-a-job-change-quiet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your departure is known to and supported by the head of the department, there is no real issue here: you can talk about your departure in any way that seems most reasonable to you.  I don't think there is any canonically best way to do it.

In my (limited) direct experience, faculty who leave but do not retire often do so without an "official" announcement.  The exceptions have occurred when we want to rehire into the position before the new academic year.  Maybe it would be better in some ways if there were an official announcement.  If you feel that way, I would talk to your chair about it and ask if they would like to make an announcement on your behalf.

> What do you say to students?

That surely depends entirely on what kind of students you have and the nature of your relationship with them, about which I know nothing and you know everything.  I presume that as a PT lecturer you have not been advising graduate students in any kind of official capacity.  But if you know of specific students for which your departure would cause a definite and substantial disruption -- well, sure, I think you should tell them as soon as you know you're leaving.  That seems to be essentially common sense.

Good luck in your new job.

Comment: Correct, I've been working with undergrads only.  But I am teaching two lecture courses this quarter and I wonder what to say to them.  Maybe just the obvious?  So long and thanks for all the fish?

Comment: @Nicole: It's really up to you, although I fear you would have to follow up "So long and thanks for all the fish" with some remedial culture lessons.  (Hope I'm wrong.)

Comment: My chair says he'll announce it to the faculty and encouraged me to announce it myself to my students.

Comment: @Nicole: Okay, sounds good.